# move an UITableViewCell with animation between 2 sections in a UITableView

Tags: iphone

In one app, there are 2 sections in an UITableView.
I hope to move an UITableViewCell with animation from one section to another section in the UITableView, is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UITableView` has the answer:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

So, delete the entry from the first row and add it to the second. There are a number of animations you can select from.

As an example (sorry doing this from memory without a compiler). Assumptions: section0Data holds data for your first section, section1Data holds it for your second.

```
[self.section0Data removeObjectAtIndex:removeIdx];
[self.section1Data insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:removeIdx inSection:0]]
                                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:1]]
                                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Also, remember that you will have to update your model to reflect what the change of section (IE delete from old one, and insert into new one).